# 'System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, using

I have the code working in .Net framework 4.5 but when i try to code the same in .Net framework 2.0, it gives compilation error

> 'System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes': type used in a
>   using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable

How to fix it?

**CODE**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {

        byte[] salt;
        byte[] subkey;
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
        {
            salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
            subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        }

        var outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
        //some more code goes here
        return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
    }
```

Comment: The error says that you can only initialize an instance of a class which is inherited from IDispossble interface and Rfc2898DeriveBytes class does not inherit IDisposable interface. That's why you are seeing this error

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That's not correct. It inherits from DeriveBytes, which does implement the IDisposable interface.

Comment: Taking a look into the documentation, it is not clear whether the IDisposable interface was implemented by the abstract DeriveBytes class back in .NET Framework 2.0...

Comment: @Samra Check if your deriveBytes variable has access to the Dispose method.. does Intellisense approve deriveBytes.Dispose() ?

Comment: `DeriveBytes` does not implement IDisposable in .net 2.0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.derivebytes(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AndréB no it doesn't Dispose in intellisence..can i simply remove the using statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you remove the `using` like:

```
 Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, 
 PBKDF2IterCount);
 salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
 subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
```

Comment: yup that's what i asked Lachlan in comments and did! :)

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from [André's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8927944/andr%C3%A9-b%20%22Andr%C3%A9) comment, it would appear that the `Dispose` method wasn't introduced until .NET 4: [DeriveBytes.Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.derivebytes.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) 
(note: "Other Versions")

You could take a look at how the `Dispose` method is implemented in the current framework and consider adapating it to your project: [Source Browser](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs,4f7664e12814cd2b,references)

Comment: Thanks Lachlan I have removed the using statement. Would that be alright or is there any better approach?